# Vacume / Osmosis watering gadget: limitations?

Tags: watering, irrigation, water

I just found a great sounding device on amazon, which apparently uses vaccume or osmosis to help water plants:

[image]

The idea behind is, that it waters the plants, only when the soil is dry.

The little hose is 70cm long.

My question is, how much "force" does this gadget have? What is this tech really called and are there variations with more performance?

With this particular version, could I use it to water my plants from a 10L canister? It would be about 30cm up to the bottle hole and down to the bottom.

Can this physical effect draw water 35cm up?

Ultimately I am trying to figure out a passive, low tech irrigation system for my garden, which is outside the city and I can't get to it frequently enough during the summer. I have about 30 tomato plants there and say 40 other vegetables.
Having a bunch of 10L canisters with these things attached to them to water my tomatoes for a few days sounds very appealing.